# Can't install pygame_sdl2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sdl-2

I'm creating a tower defense game using [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [pygame](/questions/tagged/pygame). I would like to add this one on the Google Play Store, but I need to create an [apk](/questions/tagged/apk) file.

I'm following a tutorial on GitHub:
https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example.
I follow all the instructions but can't install `pygame_sdl2`.
I use the command prompt, and use `$ python setup.py install` in the appropriate directory.

But it gave me this error :

```
C:\Users\gomes\Downloads\pygame_sdl2-master>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 59, in <module>
    parse_cflags([ "sh", "-c", "sdl2-config --cflags" ])
  File "C:\Users\gomes\Downloads\pygame_sdl2-master\setuplib.py", line 93, in parse_cflags
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, universal_newlines=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 212, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable
```

I tried to reinstall `pygame_sdl2-master`, but gave me the same result.

Comment: Bienvenue sur Stack Overflow! Veuillez excuser mon franc,ais :-) `setup.py`, in line 59, tries to run a shell that you don't have on windows. Idk why that exception isn't handled by the "except" following that line - what happens if you remove the `if not windows: raise` from lines 63-64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the appropriate Windows dependencies and [cython](/questions/tagged/cython). I did some researching and testing and found this solution:

1. Install [cython](/questions/tagged/cython), type this in a terminal:

`$ pip install cython`

2. Go to your `pygame_sdl2` directory and download the Windows dependencies by typing:

`$ git clone https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2_windeps`

If it's not in the `pygame_sdl2` directory, just move `pygame_sdl2_windeps` there manually.

3. Start building the library:

`$ python setup.py install`

Comment: When I'm typing the command "$ git clone https..." on the command prompt it is not recognized !

Comment: @Yanis As a reply to your answer, you're welcome! Also, when picking a response as an answer, please upvote it as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I directly download pygame_sdl2_windeps on github. I have copied this one one the pygame_sdl2 directory and use the "python setup.py install" command in the command prompt, and IT WORKS !!!

```
C:\PGS4A\pygame_sdl2>python
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:42:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pygame_sdl2
>>>
```

Thank you for your help !!!