# unable to install pygame_sdl2 via pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, pygame, sdl-2

I am trying to install `pygame-sdl2` on my ubuntu platform.

when I run command: `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ pygame_sdl2`  on teerminal I get this error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting pygame_sdl2
  Using cached https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/f1/8dd343ae2d97c432cf1c81ca03d2d0472396f9d8e76c677aeae9ce2ec61d/pygame_sdl2-2.1.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: 1: sdl2-config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tXTEZE/pygame-sdl2/setup.py", line 39, in <module>
        parse_cflags([ "sh", "-c", "sdl2-config --cflags" ])
      File "setuplib.py", line 93, in parse_cflags
        output = subprocess.check_output(command, universal_newlines=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 219, in check_output
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['sh', '-c', 'sdl2-config --cflags']' returned non-zero exit status 127

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-tXTEZE/pygame-sdl2/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install pygame\_sdl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954945/cant-install-pygame-sdl2)

Comment: No this is something else (I had read that earlier but didn't solve my problem) this is about sdl2-config file

Comment: @YoucefBenyettou this is related to windows dependencies, and here is for ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/renpy/pygame_sdl2#building

To compile pygame_sdl2 from sources you need SDL2, SDL2_gfx, SDL2_image, SDL2_mixer, and SDL2_ttf libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libsdl2-dev \
    libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev \
    libjpeg-dev libpng-dev
```

Comment: I have tried this earlier many times but it gives error not found[404] packages not installed try apt-get update or --fix-missing.The terminal is not able to fetch URLs :(

Comment: The only package that is not in Debian is `libpng12-dev`. The instructions seems to be a bit outdated, the current package is `libpng-dev`

Comment: I had figured this out already;my error is something like this:  Err:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libpcrecpp0v5 amd64 2:8.39-3
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Err:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates/main amd64 libudev-dev amd64 232-21ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]
Err:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libdbus-1-dev amd64 1.10.10-1ubuntu2
  404  Not Found [IP: 194.158.119.186 80]

Comment: Not related to the question. The problem is you've configured `apt` to use http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ as the package mirror but the mirror is outdated, there is no zesty at http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ Fix your `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Select another mirror or upgrade.

Comment: I am new to Ubuntu and unable to understand it.I searched but still I am unable to get it:(

Comment: Thanks.it helped and now I have finally installed it:-)